# Get value of an item from ViewData Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How to get the item associated to a key from ViewData in view ?

I mean something like that `ViewData["key"].Item`
Is it possible ?

I'm setting it from an ActionResult in Controller like this

```
ViewData["LeftUploadedData"] = Pic1;
```

and in my view

```
var uploadedImg = ViewData["LeftUploadedData"] as Picture; 
if (uploadedImg.ByteImage != null) 
{
    <img src="data:image;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(uploadedImg.ByteImage)" style="width: 100%; max-height: 100%" />
}
```

Comment: you meant asp.net mvc ?

Answer (score 4):

Also, in the view you might want to specify the item type. So if you know you are expecting an int you should cast it properly. Example:

```
@{    
   int listNumber = ViewData["key"] as Int32;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store in your method this way :

```
ViewData["key"] = "Your Data";
```

You can fetch it like this :

```
var item = @ViewData["key"];
```

Comment: @Ldh, ViewData and TempData are dictionary objects so you can store data in it using key and retrive with same key as I have shown in answer

Comment: @Ldh, [TempDataDictionary.Peek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.peek%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) you get the value without marking it for deletion with a single call. However you need to understand the difference between ViewData and TempData

Comment: @Ldh please edit your question and add your implemented code in it so it would become more readable

Comment: In fact I want to get the value from the View 
this is my code in the view

`{var uploadedImg = ViewData["LeftUploadedData"] as Picture;
      if (uploadedImg.ByteImage != null)
       {<img src="data:image;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(uploadedImg.ByteImage)" style="width: 100%; max-height: 100%" />}
`

Comment: @Ldh, no worries, so here you are getting the image from ViewData right?? and where are you setting the Image value in ViewData?

Comment: I'm setting it from an ActionResult in Controller like this 
`//some code 
 ViewData["LeftUploadedData"] = Pic1; `

Comment: and what happens, are you getting any error, or image null, what happens?? Use var uploadImage = @ViewData["LeftUploadedData"];

Comment: the image that I get is null

Comment: just try, var image = @ViewData["LeftUploadedData"]; and debug that code if you are getting image null or not, because it might be possible that there is a problem in casting the data to Picture. So just try this, if you getting anything in image without casting it.

Comment: in the view, it is always returning null object